# Technology review without code

Tags: discussion, scope

I developed a new blockchain technology. I have white papers and my code is under development.

I would like to ask a question about my technology idea and not providing actual code. Is that kind of question suitable for this Stack Exchange channel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, such a question would not be suitable here if no working code is included. See [What topics can I ask about?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for reference.

In fact, I don't think there is a site on the Stack Exchange network where such a question would be suitable, although I may be wrong, as I am not familiar with every site.

Comment: [softwareengineering.SE] might help with general design, depending on the actual question.

Comment: I would also say Software Engineering (although I can't make a promise on this one), or some site related to Crypto or Blockchain.

Comment: Maybe also [Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/)?